# Define scopes at resource level of service in Ballerina

Tags: http, service, ballerina

In the following BBE, scopes are defined at the service level.

Is there a way to define the expected scopes at the resource level?

https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-service-oauth2/

Answer (score 0):

We can do it by using `@http:ResourceConfig` annotation.

https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/http/latest#HttpResourceConfig

ex:

```
    @http:ResourceConfig {
        auth: {
            scopes: ["admin"]
        }
    }
    resource function get albums() returns Album[] {
        return [
            {title: "Blue Train", artist: "John Coltrane"},
            {title: "Jeru", artist: "Gerry Mulligan"}
        ];
    }
}
```